# Cookie not working altogether, php

Tags: php, cookies

I'm working with cookies in php, and I define some inside a class function. It's curious, because if I just specify the name, content and path, they all work, but when I also specify the domain, it doesn't work (I mean that it doesn't show in browser cookies and when I try to get it, it doesn't exist.) don't know why. My code is exactly as I described, and I'm sure there's no syntax error (basically because PhP would tell me).

```
setcookie('rememberme', $cookie_string, time() + COOKIE_RUNTIME, "/", COOKIE_DOMAIN);
```

Cokie domain is ".127.0.0.1", but i also tried with other domains, and the same.
Can somebody tell me why? Thank you.

Comment: Not working means what? Show your code first.

Comment: ok, I mean that it doesn't show in browser cookies and when I try to get it, it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help to know the value of:

```
COOKIE_RUNTIME
```

The correct syntax is:

```
setcookie(name,value,expire,path,domain,secure)
```

This works:

```
$expire=time()+60*60*24*30;
setcookie("japagou", 1, $expire, "/", "yourdomain.tld");
```

[Check some examples](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_http_setcookie.asp)

Comment: yeah, and isn't the localhost domain valid? @Tuga

Comment: check the value of localhost with `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` and set the cookie with that value.